# Angular: Proxy server truncates XHR response

Tags: express, angular-cli

In an `angular 6` project the `express` proxy server suddenly started truncating responses to XHR at 8192 characters (behavior only applies to XHR re. The content of the endpoint doesn't matter, if the response is longer than 8192 characters it gets truncated. Trimming the content returned by the problematic endpoint to less than that, response is not truncated. If i modify another endpoint to return a a JSON string longer than 8192 chars, response is truncated. No problems when i load the project into a production environment, all endpoints work as expected regardless of length.

I have removed and reinstalled `node_modules` and updated the local `ng-cli` to `6.2.9` without solving the problem. Not sure what else to try to get this solved.

Problem seems similar to https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1574, except the truncation in consistent for the problematic response size.

node: 8.14.0

npm: 6.4.1

devDependencies:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.8.9",
"@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
"@types/node": "^6.14.2",
"codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
"karma": "^3.1.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.1.0",
"karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
"protractor": "^5.4.1",
"remap-istanbul": "0.9.5",
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "^5.11.0",
"typescript": "^2.9.2",
"webpack": "^4.27.0"
```

Wasn't sure what, if any, other information to add. If there's something that would help you help me, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue, solved by updating node to the latest lts (10.15.1)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue after updating Angular 6 to Angular 7. When using a proxy server the json responses to the http requests were getting truncated resulting in a parsing error. Updating Node from 8.x to v10.15.2 and NPM to 6.4.1 fixed the issue.